# identifying string position in a list in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column(position) detailing the index position of each name, in the list of names.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'names' : [['a','b','c'], ['a','b'], ['c','d','a'], ['b','a','d','c','e'], ['e','a']], 'position':[0,1,0,2,0]})
```

I have tried converting to boolean with....

```
df['match'] = (df.apply(lambda x: [x['name'] == m for m in x['names']], axis=1))
```

but still cant get to the answer I am after.

I have looked through many posts but cant find any specific to applying index() to lists in a dataframe.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If values always match use `.index`:

```
df['match'] = (df.apply(lambda x: x['names'].index(x['name']), axis=1))
print (df)
  name            names  position  match
0    a        [a, b, c]         0      0
1    b           [a, b]         1      1
2    c        [c, d, a]         0      0
3    d  [b, a, d, c, e]         2      2
4    e           [e, a]         0      0
```

If possible no match is possibl use your solution with generator comprehension and `next` for default value if no match, here `-1`:

```
#changed data
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['r', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
                   'names' : [['a','b','c'], ['a','b'], ['c','d','a'],
                              ['b','a','d','c','e'], ['e','a']],  
                    'position':[0,1,0,2,0]})

f = lambda x: next((i for i, m in enumerate(x['names']) if x['name'] == m), -1)
df['match'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
  name            names  position  match
0    r        [a, b, c]         0     -1
1    b           [a, b]         1      1
2    c        [c, d, a]         0      0
3    d  [b, a, d, c, e]         2      2
4    e           [e, a]         0      0
```

Comment: The generator comprehension is working perfectly. The first solution is not working as apparently the 'names' column in my dataset is actually arrays not lists and so .index fails. I tried converting to lists but didn't work. Thanks a lot for your time.